# How to get one row from 1st table and others from 2nd table

Tags: c#, linq

I am having a little issue regarding a query where I want to show records from 2 tables. I need to show one row from first table and many rows from 2nd table (which relates on first table.id)

like Table 1

```
name | id
----------
Shop | 1
Shop | 2
```

table 2

```
name | id  | shopid
item | 1   |
item | 2   |
item | 3   |
```

I want to retrieve single row from table 1 and the relevant ones from table 2.

I have a object of items which contains properties for both tables but I need to show single record from table 1 (I have tried with join, and with some other way but getting more values from table 1 (1st records has info and other are empty)).

here is sample code

```
public class ItemsInfo
{
    public Shopname { get; set;}
    public item { get; set; }
}

public List<ItemsInfo> ShopItems(int ShopId)
{
    var items = from i in db.items
                join s in db.shops on i.shopid equals s.id
                where s.id == ShopId
                select new ItemsInfo
                           {
                               shopname = s.name,
                           items = i.name
                           }
    return items.Tolist();
}
```

I want result as

```
Shopname : abcd
items    : item 1
items    : item 2
items    : item 3
```

Comment: Can you show us some sample data? The expected result for that sample data? Can you show us what linq query you've tried that doesn't work?  Is it already in an object that implements `IEnumerable<T>`? If so, what is that object?

Comment: tried to join 2nd table on first but no success !

Comment: i have updated the question please have a look

Comment: When you edit a question, it's generally accepted to *not* disrupt other people's edits, especially when they improve the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found Solution :)

Created main object and added nested object of 2nd table into main object

here is code

Created 2 Objects 1 for shop table, 2nd for items

```
public class Shop
{
   /// Shop Object
   public string Shop { get; set; }
   public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
   ///Items Object
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Picture { get; set; }
}


public List<Item> ItemsList(int id)
{
   var item = from i in DB.Items
   where i.ShopId == id
   select new ShopItem
   {
      Name = i.Name,
      Picture = i.ItemPictures
   };
  return item.ToList();
}


public List<Shop> ShopItems(int ShopId)
{
   var Shopitms = from shop in DB.Shops
   where shop.Id == ShopId && shop.IsActive == true && shop.IsDeleted == false
   select new Shop
   {
      Shop = shop.Name,
      Items = ItemsList(shop.Id)
   }
return ShopItms.ToList();
}
```

Working fine :)